# Unique running value for full name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to get unique running value for full name (First_Name, Surname). The below expression is calculating based only on the First name, even when the full name is passed in.

```
RunningValue(Fields!Full_Name.Value, countdistinct,Nothing)
```

This occurs only for few names. For example:

```
169  Diana Toro

169   Dianne Alison
```

I get the full name using the below T-SQL:

`RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(prov.first_name, '')))+ ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(prov.last_name)) AS Full_Name`

How can I get this desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- Go to report layout.

-- Specify group on Full_Name for the table.

-- Then change your expression to,

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Full_Name.Value,CountDistinct,"table1_Group1")
```